# I'm trying to play a video using vlcj inside a JPanel

Tags: java, video, jpanel, vlcj

I'm trying to play a video using vlcj inside a JPanel but it doesn't work for me. The message exception I am getting is:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The video surface component must be displayable"

The code:

```
public class MediaPlayerPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    MediaPlayerFactory mediaPlayerFactory = new MediaPlayerFactory();
    EmbeddedMediaPlayer mediaPlayer = mediaPlayerFactory.newEmbeddedMediaPlayer();
    Canvas c = new Canvas();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();



    public MediaPlayerPanel()   {



        c.setBackground(Color.black);

        p.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(c, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        mediaPlayer.setVideoSurface(mediaPlayerFactory.newVideoSurface(c));
        c.setVisible(true);       
        p.setVisible(true);
    }

    public  void play(String video) {

        mediaPlayer.playMedia(video);

    }

}


public class VideoPlayer {

     public static void main(final String[] args) {

         NativeLibrary.addSearchPath(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), "C:\\Program Files\\VideoLAN\\VLC");
         Native.loadLibrary(RuntimeUtil.getLibVlcLibraryName(), LibVlc.class);

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Video Player");
            MediaPlayerPanel mpp = new MediaPlayerPanel();

            frame.setLocation(100, 100);
            frame.setSize(1050, 600);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


            frame.add(mpp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            mpp.play("E:\\Filmek\\Game.of.Thrones.S04E02.HDTV.x264-2HD\\game.of.thrones.s04e02.hdtv.x264-2hd.mp4");


     }
}
```

Comment: storno. I solved. New JPanel useless...

Comment: How did you solve it?  This may help somebody in the future.

Comment: I deleted p JPanel that was unnecessary. c Canvas was added MediaPlayerPanel.

Answer (score 0):

That error message usually means that you tried to do `mediaPlayer.play()` before you showed (or `pack()`'ed) the application frame that contains the video surface.

In the code you posted, you are not adding your panel `p` to the `MediaPlayerPanel` panel that you create. So your video surface `Canvas` is not actually attached to any visible component hierarchy.

Your `MediaPlayerPanel` should set a `BorderLayout` on itself and add `p` to that.